# How do I do a deep copy of an element in LINQ to XML?

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I want to make a deep copy of a LINQ to XML XElement.  The reason I want to do this is there are some nodes in the document that I want to create modified copies of (in the same document).  I don't see a method to do this.

I could convert the element to an XML string and then reparse it, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Daniel - I think you should reconsider the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

There is no need to reparse. One of the constructors of XElement takes another XElement and makes a deep copy of it:

```
XElement original = new XElement("original");
XElement deepCopy = new XElement(original);
```

Here are a couple of unit tests to demonstrate:

```
[TestMethod]
public void XElementShallowCopyShouldOnlyCopyReference()
{
    XElement original = new XElement("original");
    XElement shallowCopy = original;
    shallowCopy.Name = "copy";
    Assert.AreEqual("copy", original.Name);
}

[TestMethod]
public void ShouldGetXElementDeepCopyUsingConstructorArgument()
{
    XElement original = new XElement("original");
    XElement deepCopy = new XElement(original);
    deepCopy.Name = "copy";
    Assert.AreEqual("original", original.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual("copy", deepCopy.Name);
}
```

Comment: I believe that the constructor used in this example is generically known as a **Copy Constructor**. Here is the doc for the [`XElement` Copy Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There is also an [`XDocument` Copy Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Fortunately for us, **LINQ to XML** makes this easy...in general, [Deep Copying (or Cloning)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp) can many times not be so straightforward.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but the first test case has nothing to do with shallow copying. This is not a copy at all, it is second reference to the same object. You can apply the same principle to all non-primitive types in C#.

Comment: The [docs show exactly this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement__ctor_System_Xml_Linq_XElement_), and explain _"The following example creates an XML tree, creates a clone of the tree, and then calls DeepEquals, which tests whether the two XML trees are equal."_. In the example, a node is added after the copy-constructor is called, and with `DeepEquals` it is shown that the two nodes are now different.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the ToString and reparse method is the best way.  Here is the code:

```
XElement copy = XElement.Parse(original.ToString());
```

Comment: then DstNode.Add(copy) to add it. Done.

Answer (score 5):

Lifted directly from [C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527578):

When a node or attribute is added to an element (whether via functional construction or an Add method) the node or attribute's Parent property is set to that element. A node can have only one parent element: if you add an already parented node to a second parent, the node is automatically deep-cloned. In the following example, each customer has a separate copy of address:

```
var address = new XElement ("address",
                  new XElement ("street", "Lawley St"),
                  new XElement ("town", "North Beach")
              );
var customer1 = new XElement ("customer1", address);
var customer2 = new XElement ("customer2", address);

customer1.Element ("address").Element ("street").Value = "Another St";
Console.WriteLine (
  customer2.Element ("address").Element ("street").Value);   // Lawley St
```

This automatic duplication keeps X-DOM object instantiation free of side effects—another hallmark of functional programming.

Comment: This was a very keen observation at the time, and it is indeed exactly [what happens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement__ctor_System_Xml_Linq_XElement_) (see example code there).

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
var copy = new XElement(original.Name, original.Attributes(),
                        original.Elements() );
```

Comment: No it doesn't. This way you forget to copy comments, text nodes, processing instructions, inherited namespace nodes, annotations, base-uri etc. A better way is to use the copy-constructor `new XElement(original)`.

Answer (score -3):

I do not believe there is an existing mechanism that allows you to perform a deep copy of an XNode style tree.  I think you are left with two options.

1. Do as you suggested an convert to a string and then back into a tree
2. Write on yourself with a visitor pattern

The visitor pattern is certainly possible but it will take a good deal of work an testing.  I think your best option is #1.