# Algorithm for xml document splitting

Tags: c#, xml, algorithm

I want to split an xml document into several xml documents by specified node name, (similar with string.Split(...).)

Example: I have the following xml document.

```
<root>
    <nodeA>
        Hello
    </nodeA>
    <nodeA>
        <nodeB>
            node b Text
        </nodeB>
        <nodeImage>
            image.jpg
        </nodeImage>
    </nodeA>
    <nodeA>
        node a text
    </nodeA>
</root>
```

I want to split this xml document into 3 parts by 'nodeImage', and keep the original xml structure. (Note: the node with name 'nodeImage' could be anywhere)
1. xml before nodeImage
2. xml for nodeImage
3. xml after nodeImage

For the sample xml, the results should be:

XML Document 1:

```
<root>
    <nodeA>
        Hello
    </nodeA>
    <nodeA>
        <nodeB>
            node b Text
        </nodeB>
    </nodeA>
</root>
```

XML Document 2:

```
<root>
    <nodeA>
        <nodeImage>
            image.jpg
        </nodeImage>
    </nodeA>
</root>
```

XML Document 3:

```
<root>
    <nodeA>
        node a text
    </nodeA>
</root>
```

Does anyone know if there is a good algorithm, or existing code sample for this requirement?

**Update Notes:**
If there is only one node with the name 'nodeImage' in the xml document, then this xml document should always be splitted into 3 xml documents.

Comment: Can you go over your question, and check that the result you want to achieve is really the documents you've typed?
It looks like 'XML Document 1' should only have the first 'NodeA' in it...

Comment: Does [this answer help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12672654/2065121)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912109/split-xml-document-apart-creating-multiple-output-files-from-repeating-elements.

Comment: Please show your implementation code.

Comment: @AlexCube check my answer, I think it does what you need

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement xe = XElement.Load(XMLFile);

foreach(XElement newXE in xe.Elements("nodeA"))
{
    XElement root = new XElement("root",newXE);
    root.Save(newFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i want.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The output doesn't match the expectation. See question

Answer (score 1):

The term "split" is slightly confusing. Splitting on one ocurrence does not usually produce three parts.

I start by trying to define your question in Linq to xml terms. 
For every occurrence of XDocument.Descendants("nodeImage") you want to create:

- A copy of the document where the nodeImage parent has the nodeImage and all succeeding nodes removed. In addition all ancestors must have all nextnodes removed.
- A copy of the document where all ancestors of the nodeImage element have all XElement.NextNodes and XElement.PreviousNodes removed.
- Running this check again on a copy of the XDocument where all Ancestor PreviousNodes have been removed.
- If no occurrence is found. The document being checked is returned in its entirety.

A deep copy of XDocument is easy. It has a copy constructor.
Of course, this will be a hog on memory if your xml is of a significant size.

However, the challenge is to locate your node in every copy.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209595/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-element-in-linq-to-xml) shows how you can get the XPath of an element. You can use that.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, using [System.Xml.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387098.aspx)?

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(stringxml);
var res = new List<XElement>();
var cur = new XElement("root");
foreach (var node in doc.Element("root").Elements("nodeA"))
{
    if (node.Element("nodeImage") == null)
    {
        cur.Add(node);
    }
    else
    {
        res.Add(cur);
        res.Add(new XElement("root", node));
        cur = new XElement("root");
    }
}
res.Add(cur);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Test it extensively.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<root>
<nodeA>
    Hello
</nodeA>
<nodeA>
    <nodeB>
        node b Text
    </nodeB>
    <nodeImage>
        image.jpg
    </nodeImage>
</nodeA>
<nodeA>
    node a text
</nodeA></root>");

var xmlFrags = new List<string>();
string xml = "<root>";
bool bNewFragment = true;
foreach (XmlNode nodeA in doc.SelectNodes("//root/nodeA")) {
    XmlNode nodeImage = nodeA.SelectSingleNode("nodeImage");
    if (nodeImage != null) {
        xml += "<nodeA>";
        var en = nodeA.GetEnumerator();
        while (en.MoveNext()) {
            XmlNode xn = (XmlNode)en.Current;
            if (xn != nodeImage)
            xml += xn.OuterXml;
        }
        xml += "</nodeA></root>";
        xmlFrags.Add(xml);
        xml = "<root><nodeA>" + nodeImage.OuterXml + "</nodeA></root>";
        xmlFrags.Add(xml);
        bNewFragment = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (bNewFragment) {
            xml = "<root>";
            bNewFragment = false;
        }
        xml += nodeA.OuterXml;
    }
}
if (!bNewFragment) {
    xml += "</root>";
    xmlFrags.Add(xml);
}
//Use the XML fragments as you like
foreach (var xmlFrag in xmlFrags)
    Console.WriteLine(xmlFrag + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create the XML documents
        XmlDocument
            doc1 = new XmlDocument(),
            doc2 = new XmlDocument(),
            doc3 = new XmlDocument();

        // load the initial XMl into doc1
        doc1.Load("input.xml");

        // create the structure of doc2 and doc3
        doc2.AppendChild(doc2.ImportNode(doc1.FirstChild, false));
        doc3.AppendChild(doc3.ImportNode(doc1.FirstChild, false));
        doc2.AppendChild(doc2.ImportNode(doc1.DocumentElement, false));
        doc3.AppendChild(doc3.ImportNode(doc1.DocumentElement, false));

        // select the nodeImage
        var nodeImage = doc1.SelectSingleNode("//nodeImage");
        if (nodeImage != null)
        {
            // append to doc3
            var node3 = nodeImage.ParentNode.NextSibling;
            var n3 = doc3.ImportNode(node3, true);
            doc3.DocumentElement.AppendChild(n3);

            // append to doc2
            var n2 = doc2.ImportNode(nodeImage.ParentNode, true);
            n2.RemoveChild(n2.SelectSingleNode("//nodeImage").PreviousSibling);
            doc2.DocumentElement.AppendChild(n2);

            // remove from doc1
            nodeImage.ParentNode.ParentNode
                .RemoveChild(nodeImage.ParentNode.NextSibling);
            nodeImage.ParentNode
                .RemoveChild(nodeImage);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(doc1.InnerXml);
        Console.WriteLine(doc2.InnerXml);
        Console.WriteLine(doc3.InnerXml);
    }
}
```